# Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers error related to compiling/building C++ program in Mac OS X

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos

I'm having issues with having a clean build when building a C++ project using Eclipse CPP in my Mac OS. I already tried to add the path to the include directory for c++ in project properties but I'm still getting this error. My Mac OS is OS X El Capitan version 10.11.5 and my Eclipse version is Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Version: Mars Release (4.5.0) and Build id: 20150621-1200.

Does anyone have an idea whats wrong?

```
12:25:09 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Greetings ****
make all 
Building target: Greetings
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++  -o "Greetings"  ./greetings.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))", referenced from:
      _main in greetings.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in greetings.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in greetings.o
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in greetings.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      _main in greetings.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in greetings.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Greetings] Error 1

12:25:11 Build Finished (took 1s.112ms)
```